# Are there any open cover tools or extensions available for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report, code-coverage, opencover

I was trying to extract coverage report of my application using following command

```
OpenCover.Console.exe ^
-register:user ^
-target:"mstest.exe" ^
-targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"C:\myapp\bin\myapp.dll\" /resultsfile:\"myapp.trx\"" ^
-filter:"+[myapp*]* -[myapp.Test]* -[*]myapp.RouteConfig" ^
-mergebyhash ^
-skipautoprops ^
-output:"myapp.xml"
```

Then report

```
.\ReportGenerator.exe ^
-reports:"F:\OpenCover\myapp.xml" ^
-targetdir:"ReportGenerator"
```

But I'm getting the following errors when running open cover?

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong with command?

PS: I have already registered open cover profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using mstest.exe instead of [vstest.console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) for running test cases in [open cover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover)

Here is batch file code snippet to extract coverage report using open-cover.

```
::Note:Before running this file, make sure opencover and reportgenerator installed in your system
::Download and read about opencover : https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover
::You can read about vstest.console command line documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

::Set your project and report location's base path here
SET basePath=C:\MyProject
SET targetReportDir=F:\MyProject
SET targetHtmlReportDir=F:\MyProject\ReportGenerator

::Replace your test project Dll's path here
SET unitTestDlls=%basePath%\Demo.BusinessData\bin\Debug\Demo.BusinessData.Test.dll %basePath%\Demo.Cache.Test\bin\Debug\Demo.Cache.Test.dll


echo Test cases are running...
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"%unitTestDlls%" -filter:"+[Demo*]* -[Demo*Test]* -[Demo*Test.Core]* -[Demo*Tests]*" -output:%targetReportDir%\DemoFullReport.xml -mergebyhash


echo Coverage report is preparing and will be saved to %targetHtmlReportDir%\Demo location
ReportGenerator.exe -reports:"%targetReportDir%\DemoFullReport.xml" -targetdir:"%targetHtmlReportDir%\Demo"
```

Key points to check before running this batch file

1. Make sure vstest.console environent is setup or run in visual studio command line.
2. Make sure, your opencover is setup and accssible through command line.
3. Make sure opencover report generator is setup and accssible through command line.

Thanks